# Servlet 3.0's MultipartConfig don't work with UrlRewriteFilter?

Tags: java, servlets, upload, multipart, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am now coding with a Servlet to process file upload request.
I use tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter to help me rewrite URL, and I want to use servlet 3.0's fileupload support to finish the file saving operations.
But the problem is, After UrlRewriteFilter did its dispatch to the servlet, the servlet can not receive multipart data by calling request.getParts() or request.getPart("partname").

Here is the xml code in urlrewrite.xml:

```
<rule>
    <note>处理文件上传请求</note>
    <condition type="method">POST</condition>
    <from>^/upload/(\w+?)/(\w+?)/([a-zA-Z_0-9/\.\-]*)$</from>
    <set type="parameter" name="db">$1</set>
    <set type="parameter" name="bucket">$2</set>
    <set type="parameter" name="filename">$3</set>
    <to>/servlet/uploadFileServlet</to>
</rule>
```

Here is the main code for the file upload servlet, looks simple ^_^:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/servlet/uploadFileServlet")
@MultipartConfig()
public class UploadFileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();

        System.out.println("parts : " + parts);
        System.out.println("params : " + request.getParameterMap());

        request.getPart("filepart").write("myfile.txt");
    }
}
```

And Here is the Jsp code to select file and submit. There are two forms for contrast. The 1st one directly send request to the servlet, then the servlet can recieve multipart data. But the 2nd one, whose url matched the urlrewrite role, dispatched to the servlet, and the servlet can not recieve multipart data, That is the problem.

```
<form action="servlet/uploadFileServlet?db=game_dev&bucket=videos&filename=hello.txt"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="filepart" />
    <input type="text" name="myinfo" value="hello123下午好hello">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<form action="upload/game_dev/videos/helloworld.txt"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="filepart" />
    <input type="text" name="myinfo" value="hello456下午好lala">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Can Anyone help me solve this problem?